# Remove vote to close after a question has been edited

Tags: support

I voted to close [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/121097/agile-scrum-and-uml-round-trip-tools) question before it was edited. After the edit it think the question is of much higher quality and I dont want it closed. There dosent seem to be any way of revoking a close vote (unlike normal votes which can be changed if the question is edited).

Is this an oversight or a delibrate feature? (If the latter then why?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a deliberate feature.

If no one else votes to close your vote will decay in a few days and the post will remain open. You can add a comment to state that you no longer think the question should be closed - this might stop others casting their vote.

If the post is closed you can then vote to reopen. If 4 others (or a moderator) agree the post will be reopened. If you think that it won't get the required votes then flag it for moderator attention and we'll review it and cast a vote if we agree.

In the immediate term doing nothing is the right option to let the community speak.

In extremis a moderator can close and then reopen the question to clear all the current votes.

Comment: I thought your last sentence said "an extremist moderator" at first.

Comment: Whats the thinking behind it being a deliberate feature? Your answer kind of says "if you don't want to vote to close anymore, here are some things to do to get round this" when rather than waiting to make reopen votes or leave comments it seems easier to just be able to remove a close vote.

Comment: @MoominTroll - I'm not 100% sure. This issue has been raised on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) several times so it would be worth searching there. [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes) for example, and [particularly this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-about-a-vote-not-to-close-option-to-counter-the-vote-to-close)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'll have a read.